# R: Populating a matrix using data from two other matrices using condition

Tags: r

I am new to `R`. I have two matrices:

```
Amat<-matrix(data=c(11:20,NA,NA,NA,NA,25:30),nrow = 4,ncol = 5)

Bmat<-matrix(data=c(1:6,NA,NA,NA,NA,11:20),nrow = 4,ncol = 5)
```

I want to build a third matrix `Cmat` of dimension 4x5 (same as `Amat` & `Bmat`) in such a way that data from `Amat` and `Bmat` are comapred as below:

```
if(is.na(Amat)!="TRUE" && is.na(Bmat)!="TRUE") {1} else {0}
```

i.e. `Cmat` should be filled with '1' for the respective position if both matrices (`Amat` & `Bmat`) doesn't have `NA`.
Can anyone help me to approach for this without going for loop? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please see here [how to format code](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do this by coercing the logical matrix (`!is.na(Amat) & !is.na(Bmat)`) to binary (`+`)

```
Cmat <-  +(!is.na(Amat) & !is.na(Bmat))
Cmat
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
#[1,]    1    1    0    0    1
#[2,]    1    1    0    0    1
#[3,]    1    0    0    1    1
#[4,]    1    0    0    1    1
```

Or other variations include

```
 +(!is.na(Amat*Bmat))
```

Or

```
+(!is.na(Amat + Bmat))
```